# LWC - Modal Prompt - how to get user input message onclick "Ok"

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

I implemented the Modal Prompt in my LWC
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_dialog_prompt

The documentation does not explain how to grab the user input message when they click "Ok" button.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the documentation is quite clear, check the [JS part](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-prompt/documentation) on how to get the response, you can use the `async-await` variant of it like this:

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-button onclick={handlePromptClick} label="Open Prompt Modal">
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import LightningPrompt from 'lightning/prompt';

export default class PromptExample extends LightningElement {
    async handlePromptClick() {
        const response = await LightningPrompt.open({
            label: 'Please Respond!',
            message: 'This is the prompt message.',
            defaultValue: 'Optional initial input value',
        });
        console.log(response);
    }

}
```

> - When user clicks on `cancel button`, the response will be `null`
> - When user clicks on `ok button`, response will be the value in the input field